# Как работают аргументы функции reduce()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Снизу вы увидите пример обыкновенной функции, которая описана с помощью метода reduce(). Объясните пожалуйста как она работает, как она записывает данные в переменную. Не могу разобраться.

```js
const composition = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((acc, curItem, curIndex) => {
  console.log(curIndex + ": " + curItem + ", currentValue: " + acc);
  return acc * curItem;
}, 1);
```

```
//Вывод
0: 1, currentValue: 1// (здесь начальное значение 1,которое мы задали после функции,
//умножается на первый элемент равный 1.

1: 2, currentValue: 1
2: 3, currentValue: 2
3: 4, currentValue: 6
4: 5, currentValue: 24
```

Comment: Ну по определению, первый аргумент `acc` получает то значение, которое вернула функция на предыдущем круге... здесь - умножает его на текущий элемент и через `return` отправляет его на следующий круг, где acc уже примит новое значение. Если напишете `return 10` - на каждом круге acc будет получать значение `10` )

Comment: acc - значение, которая функция вернула на прошлом круге, но тогда какое у нее значение, если метод допустим начинает свою 1 итерацию?

Comment: @Torin_21 вторым параметром функции `reduce` указывается начальное значение. В Вашем примере цифра 1. Может указываться массив и т.д. всё зависит от задачи!

Comment: То есть эта цифра 1 в примере и есть начальное значение acc?

Comment: @Torin_21 да. на первой итерации умножается 1*1 далее после `return` начинается следующая итерация и на вход приходит результат умножения. и далее умножается 1*2 и т.д. (1 так как результат 1*1 = 1 соответственно)

Comment: в справке по функции [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) описаны все параметры и как все работает